Running a worker dyno (continuously) with a web dyno
I have an app that needs a celery worker to run.  When I go to my Heroku dashboard, it seems like I can't toggle on the worker dyno.  Is this because I have a basic plan?  Do I need to have a different plan in order to run the worker dyno continuously, without having to initiate it manually (herokou run worker)? Thanks all for any advice!
I tried to toggle on the worker dyno in my Heroku dashboard, but it doesn't allow me to do that.
